# Discord bot (python) edit own message itself every minute

Tags: python, discord, bots

```py
import os
import discord
import requests
import time
import datetime

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=0, name='HIDDENSTATUS'))
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
        
    async def on_message(self, message):
        msglower = message.content.lower()
        channelStatusSV = client.get_channel(HIDDENCHANNELID)  
        if msglower == '!refresh':
            standard = formated_info('HIDDENIP', '36963', 'ok')         
            messageStandard = await channelStatusSV.fetch_message(HIDDENMESSAGEID)
            await messageStandard.edit(content=standard)   

client = MyClient()
client.run('HIDDENTOKEN')
```

This is the full script (with some hidden info like IP, URL, etc).

It fetches my game server info into an embedded bot message. Currently, it fetches info on demand.

How can I change it to automatically fetch every minute?

Comment: You can use the triple backtick notation to make one large codeblock that's more nicely formatted than what you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using `discord.py`; you can use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)! Have it loop on the interval you want, query the server, and update the message.

Comment: could you reply with the edited code?

Comment: Did you try it yourself...? There are examples in the link and on the docs. Give it a go and see where you get stuck - hopefully not at all!